# Reading sas7bdat as pandas dataframe from zipfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sas

I have a zip file called `myfile.zip`, which contains a file `mysasfile.sas7bdat`, which I would like to read as a pandas dataframe. I've tried a few things which haven't worked, but here is my current methodology:

```
import zipfile

zipfile = zipfile.ZipFile('myfile.zip', 'r')
sasfile = zipfile.open('mysasfile.sas7bdat')

df = pd.read_sas(sasfile)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-6d55436287b5> in <module>()
      3 imgfile = archive.open('curated_dataset_preview.sas7bdat')
      4 
----> 5 df = pd.read_sas(imgfile)

/opt/python/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/sas/sasreader.py in read_sas(filepath_or_buffer, format, index, encoding, chunksize, iterator)
     38         filepath_or_buffer = _stringify_path(filepath_or_buffer)
     39         if not isinstance(filepath_or_buffer, compat.string_types):
---> 40             raise ValueError(buffer_error_msg)
     41         try:
     42             fname = filepath_or_buffer.lower()

ValueError: If this is a buffer object rather than a string name, you must specify a format string
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the parameter `format`

```
import zipfile

zipfile = zipfile.ZipFile('myfile.zip', 'r')
sasfile = zipfile.open('mysasfile.sas7bdat')

df = pd.read_sas(sasfile, format='sas7bdat')
```

Comment: I'm now getting a new error on `df = pd.read_sas(sasfile, format='sas7bdat')`

Comment: The error is `raise ValueError('unknown SAS format')` `UnsupportedOperation: seek`